# Subscribing an Amazon Mobile Push endpoint on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I have had trouble programmatically having my application subscribe endpoints to Amazon's mobile push service. I keep getting the "SNSInvalidParameterException". Below is the code I am using to get devices running my iOS application to subscribe.

```
-(NSString*)deviceTokenAsString:(NSData*)deviceTokenData {
NSString *rawDeviceTring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceTokenData];
NSString *noSpaces = [rawDeviceTring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString *tmp1 = [noSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

return [tmp1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
}

//Callback after the app registers for push
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
//Amazon
AmazonSNSClient *snsClient = [[AmazonSNSClient alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"myAccessKey" withSecretKey:@"mySecretKey"];


SNSCreatePlatformEndpointRequest *endpointRequest = [SNSCreatePlatformEndpointRequest new];
endpointRequest.token = [self deviceTokenAsString:newDeviceToken];
endpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = @"myAppARN";
[snsClient createPlatformEndpoint:endpointRequest];
}
```

The program always crashes on the [snsClient createPlatformEndpoint:endpointRequest] line. I do have the permissions for push notifications setup within the app. The only thing I can imagine is wrong is either the appARN is incorrect or the token I entered is incorrect. However, the ARN I am using is directly copy pasted from my amazon web console, and the formula I am using to create the token as an NSString is something that multiple other posts on this website have shown working for people. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss the next line: (after the "AmazonSNSClient *snsClient = "...

snsClient.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints snsEndpoint: /*your_aws_AmazonRegion*/ ];

after that - all is perfect!!